# dynamically insert div after row containing floating divs jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Edit 2: I found an answer, please mark this question as duplicate. [Get the last div in a row of floating divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846432/get-the-last-div-in-a-row-of-floating-divs) Thanks!**

*Edit: `style="clear:both;width:100%"` won't work when adding the new div after the first or second div, only if the user clicks on the right div. But it should work for all divs from any row.*

I would like to *insert a div after a row containing floating divs*. Like in itunes after tapping on a album and the detailed part appears.

So this is how it looks **before** there is a new div:

```
------  ------  ------
float:   right    div  
------  ------  ------

------  ------
float:   right
------  ------
```

And **after** adding the div it should change to:

```
------  ------  ------
float:   right    div
------  ------  ------

+++++++++
+New div+
+++++++++

------  ------
float:   right
------  ------
```

I am trying to figure out to do it, but cause all the divs are **floating** elements I haven't managed to do that yet. Is it possible ?

Comment: Some of your code would be nice.

Comment: Just add the new div with style="clear:both;width:100%". That will make it clear all floats and fill the window below the div it's inserted after.

Comment: @Gregg Duncan please check the answer edit

Comment: Do you know how many divs are in a row beforehand?

Comment: @Cedric Reichenbach No, it's an image browser. So it is always different.