# JQuery: Find last component in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a loop code like this to generate a thumbnail:

```
{products.map(x => {
    let logo = "/products/" + folder + "/" + x.filename + ".jpg";
    return <NavLink to={"/products/" + folder + "/" + x.filename} key={x.filename} id={x.filename}>
        <img src={logo} className="product" />
        <div><span className="caption">{x.name}</span></div>
    </NavLink>
})}
```

yes, it is react, but what I want to ask doesn't have anything to do with React.

CSS is like this:

```
div#items {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

So, all `NavLink` are aligned next to each other until end of row, and wrapped to the next, like this:
[image: Sample thumbnail]

Now, if I click the one with "01-coco-banana" for example, or anything in the first row, I to get `NavLink` id of 3 containers at the right on the first row, or in the other word, the fourth image in this picture.

The grid is using wrap, so it can resize and fit more thumbnails. So when user make their window smaller like this below,
[image: Second thumbnail]
I need it to return the third image instead of fourth.

The question is, how to determine which `<NavLink>` is the last `<NavLink>` in the row that user just clicked?

Please note, that images has same size only in this development purpose. The real image has their own various width and length. So you cannot divide screen size by image length.

Thank you

Comment: No. I want to determine the last NavLink component on the row where the NavLink clicked, to inser `<spec>` component. Kinda $(this).lastInARow();

Comment: You can get reference from question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846432/get-the-last-div-in-a-row-of-floating-divs , where jsfiddle had been shared http://jsfiddle.net/jqmPc/1/ which checks first left position of div with class preview. Mark the first & last div in a row, which might be helpful to you.

Comment: I possible solution I see if the row height is always te same: Grab the coordinates (`getBoundingClientRect`). If you know current coordinates, you should be able to compute which row is clicked.

Comment: @PrasadWargad Thank you. that helps. I can modify it from there so that it won't need a mark. How to accept your answer as answer?

Comment: Thanks, you can just up-vote the comment.